# Concatenate values from two dataframes, based on two sets of indices, in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframes:

```
test1 = pd.DataFrame({'id_A' : [1,2,3,4,5,6],
                     'value_A' : 6*['dog']})

test2 = pd.DataFrame({'id_B' : [1,3,5],
                     'value_B' : 3*['cat']})
```

and I want to obtain a dataframe in which, where `id_A` = `id_B`, the two strings are concatenated (`id_B` becomes 0 where it does not correspond to `id_A`),

```
id_A  | id_B  | final_value
1        1       'dog, cat'
2        0       'dog'
3        1       'dog, cat'
4        0       'dog'
5        1       'dog, cat'
```

Of course there are many such labels, not just two.

I am now trying something like map, but it does not seem to work:

```
test1['value_A'] = test2['id_B'].map(df1.value_A + df2.set_index('id_B')['value_B'])
```

I need to somehow concatenate the two strings and add them to a new column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for check membership and then change your `map` solution with mainly add [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
#if need indicator column
test1['id_B'] = test1['id_A'].isin(test2['id_B']).astype(int)
#if need id_B values
#test1['id_B'] = test1['id_A'].where(test1['id_A'].isin(test2['id_B']), 0)
s = test1.value_A + ', '+ test2.set_index('id_B')['value_B']
test1['final_value'] = test1['id_A'].map(s).fillna(test1.pop('value_A'))
print (test1)
   id_A  id_B final_value
0     1     1    dog, cat
1     2     0         dog
2     3     1    dog, cat
3     4     0         dog
4     5     1    dog, cat
5     6     0         dog
```